# how to load dynamic array from vector in android?

Tags: android

how to load dynamic  array from vector in android?

Comment: To get more complete answers, you'll want to be more descriptive when asking questions.

Comment: In my application i used SQLServer for database.I get the data from database by using web service that stored in vector.My vector contains USER_ID and NAME.Now i want to add Name list to Spinner.I don't know how to add to spinner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int count = vector.size();
String[] array = new String[count];
vector.copyInto(array);
```

to add it to spinner try this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how to add this array to spinner

Comment: @deepthi: That's a new question.

Comment: This should do it.
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);       
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
Upvoted Roman's comment. Should be another question :)

Comment: hey thanq  veru much its working.

Comment: you could also consider accepting the answer. thats another way of saying thank you.